# Why do we need to exclude arm64 architecture

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I was looking at the jitsi meet iOS sdk: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet-ios-sdk-releases

In the Sdk podspec they have `EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64'`

Can anyone help me in figuring out why they would've added this in their `podspec`

Their complete podfile

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'JitsiMeetSDK'
  s.version          = '3.6.0'
  s.summary          = 'Jitsi Meet iOS SDK'
  s.description      = 'Jitsi Meet is a WebRTC compatible, free and Open Source video conferencing system that provides browsers and mobile applications with Real Time Communications capabilities.'
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet-ios-sdk-releases'
  s.license          = 'Apache 2'
  s.authors          = 'The Jitsi Meet project authors'
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet-ios-sdk-releases.git', :tag => s.version }

  s.platform         = :ios, '11.0'

  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/JitsiMeetSDK.xcframework', 'Frameworks/WebRTC.xcframework'
  
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
  s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
end
```

Comment: Because one (or both) frameworks: `JitsiMeetSDK`/`WebRTC` isn't compiled for this architecture I guess.

Comment: Normally is due the fact that it does not support M1 architecture, therefore for simulator (so running on MacOS) it can run only with x86_64

Answer (score 2):

`EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64'`

On M1 Macs you have to exclude arm64 for simulator otherwise it won't compile.
If you are not on M1 you can remove that exclusion and it should work.